# How to get all the domains hosted on the same server

Tags: java, perl, networking, reverse-dns

How to find all the domains hosted on the same server. I tried to do a reverse ip lookup but it only give me the name of the host that the web server is running on. I would like to know something like this.

Input = yahoo.com or its ip address.
Output = should have all the domains hosted on that IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS doesn't work like that. It doesn't support true reverse lookups. The IP -> name lookups that it is able to do are really just a hack based upon forward lookups.

Comment: I actually a way to get all the domains hosted on a given host. please see below for a small perl script that will print all the domains hosted on a given host. 

https://github.com/Sheshagiri/GetDomainNames/blob/master/getDomainName.pl